# Sharing files using file manager apps server does not work windows 11

Tags: file-transfer, file-management, sharing, file-server, wifi-transfer

I tried solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/605452/connect-from-android-es-file-explorer-to-windows-7-share) but did not work. I used to create a server in any file manager and access the address like this http://192.168.1.5:5241 in Chrome without any problem but now the browser keep loading then display This site can’t be reached

I tried many files managers from the store but none worked.

Comment: I share files from Windows 11 Pro to / from Windows 11 Pro and same combinations of Windows 10 Pro. I use Windows 11 File Explorer and 10 File Explorer. Did you try File Explorer?

Comment: yes look into my answer below

Comment: It would be worth describing your actual problem in more detail. What machines are you connecting from, what you are connecting to, what you are actually trying to achieve. Saying you tried a solution from elsewhere is fine, but it doesn't necessarily tell us about your current problem or what is not working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I enable network file sharing and I had to access this address `ftp` from file explorer it worked but for the browser I have to use Asus file manager to use `http`. Other apps are not free.

Answer (score 1):

File sharing with Windows 11 is fairly straightforward.

I share files from Windows 11 Pro to / from Windows 11 Pro and same combinations of Windows 10 Pro. I use Windows 11 File Explorer and 10 File Explorer for this. Try File Explorer?

Folders can also be mapped (all the above combinations) with NET USE X: \.......  or File Explorer, Map Network Folder.

Once mapped, any decent file manager works fine.

I have, and frequently use xPlorer2 (Zabkat) and it works fine as well.

So all normal ways work.